# Using sqlmap --crawl without asking questions

Tags: sqlmap

I'm using sqlmap with `--crawl` option. Whenever a URL is found, it asks me whether to scan it

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:80/demo/sqli.php?id=1
do you want to test this URL? [Y/n/q]
```

How should I ask sqlmap to test all URLs without asking?

P.S SQLmap also asks the following questions, I'd like to answer them automatically as well:

- please enter number of threads? [Enter for 1 (current)]
- do you want to check for the existence of site's sitemap(.xml) [y/N]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this out:

```
 --answers="follow=Y" --batch
```

From SQLmap wiki:

> Act in non-interactive mode Switch: --batch
>
> If you want sqlmap to run as a batch tool, without any user's
>   interaction when sqlmap requires it, you can force that by using
>   switch --batch. This will leave sqlmap to go with a default behaviour
>   whenever user's input would be required.
>
> Set answers for questions Option: --answers
>
> In case that user wants to automatically set up answers for questions,
>   even if --batch is used, using this option he can do it by providing
>   any part of question together with answer after an equal sign. Also,
>   answers for different question can be split with delimiter character
>   ,.

Everything is [here](https://github.com/sqlmapproject/sqlmap/wiki/Usage)